# yii query not caching when using createCommand

Tags: caching, yii, memcached

I have the following query being logged in mysql which is not being cached.

```
SELECT
                        *,
                        round(priceperkm * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM),
                                4) AS NEWVALUE,
                        round(PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM),
                                2) AS TotalPriceForItem,
                        SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) AS KM_Completed,
                        round(SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE,
                                2) AS TotalPrice,
                        if(round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM)) * 100,
                                2)>100,100,round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM)) * 100,
                                2)) AS TotalPercent
                    FROM
                        hdb.projects
                            join
                        biditems ON projects.id = biditems.project_id
                            join
                        lookupprocess ON biditems.ITEMID = lookupprocess.biditems_id
                            left join
                        jobsprocesscomplete ON lookupprocess.ID = lookupprocess_id
                            left join
                        detailsseismic ON jobsprocesscomplete.JOBNO = detailsseismic.JOBNO
                                    where
                                    projects.PROJID = '1407075'
                                    and lookupprocess.ID = 16299
```

The Yii code is as follows.

```
    $dependancy = new CDbCacheDependency("select last_modified_date from projects where PROJID = $projid");
$countJobs = Jobs::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependancy)->count(array("condition"=>"PROJID=$projid"));
    foreach ($processstages as $k=>$v) {

$sql = "SELECT
                        *,
                        round(priceperkm * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM),
                                4) AS NEWVALUE,
                        round(PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM),
                                2) AS TotalPriceForItem,
                        SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) AS KM_Completed,
                        round(SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE,
                                2) AS TotalPrice,
                        if(round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM)) * 100,
                                2)>100,100,round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, projects.KM)) * 100,
                                2)) AS TotalPercent
                    FROM
                        hdb.projects
                            join
                        biditems ON projects.id = biditems.project_id
                            join
                        lookupprocess ON biditems.ITEMID = lookupprocess.biditems_id
                            left join
                        jobsprocesscomplete ON lookupprocess.ID = lookupprocess_id
                            left join
                        details".$type['type']." ON jobsprocesscomplete.JOBNO = details".$type['type'].".JOBNO
                                    where
                                    projects.PROJID = :pid
                                    and lookupprocess.ID = :lid
                                    ";

    $command = Yii::app()->db->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependancy)->createCommand($sql); // need to set memecahce to 50m to cache this query
                //Yii::log("select last_modified_date from projects where PROJID = $projid",CLogger::LEVEL_INFO, __METHOD__);
                $command->bindValue(":lid",$k,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $command->bindValue(":pid",$projid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                Yii::log((memory_get_peak_usage(true))/1024/1024 . "MB",CLogger::LEVEL_INFO, __METHOD__);
                $query = $command->query();
    }
```

I cannot seem to figure out why it is not caching these results as the `last_modified_date` is not changing. i have set max item cache to 32m and memcache memory to 512.

I have rewrote my query to as below which gets cached but the `createCommand` way it does not

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select = '
                                round(priceperkm * IFNULL(KMPlanned, t.KM),
                                            4) AS NEWVALUE,
                                    round(PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, t.KM),
                                            2) AS TotalPriceForItem,
                                    SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) AS KM_Completed,
                                    round(SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE,
                                            2) AS TotalPrice,
                                    if(round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, t.KM)) * 100,
                                            2)>100,100,round((SUM(((abs(FSP - LSP) + 1) * SI) / 1000) * PRICE) / (PRICE * IFNULL(KMPlanned, t.KM)) * 100,
                                            2)) AS TotalPercent';
            $criteria->join = 'join biditems ON t.id = biditems.project_id ';
            $criteria->join .= 'join lookupprocess ON biditems.ITEMID = lookupprocess.biditems_id ';
            $criteria->join .= 'left join jobsprocesscomplete ON lookupprocess.ID = lookupprocess_id ';
            $criteria->join .= 'left join details'.$type['type'].' ON jobsprocesscomplete.JOBNO = details'.$type['type'].'.JOBNO ';
            $criteria->compare('t.PROJID',$projid);
            $criteria->compare('lookupprocess.ID',$k);

            Projects::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependancy)->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: MAYBE self::CACHE_TIMEOUT in  Yii::app()->db->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependancy), I don't know where you constant is defined

Comment: @darkheir constant is set to 3600

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->cache(self::CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependancy)
    ->createCommand($sql)
    ->bindValue(":lid",$k,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    ->bindValue(":pid",$projid,PDO::PARAM_INT)
    ->findAll();
```

I assumed that `CACHE_TIMEOUT` was a constant in this class, but if it is defined in another class, then you need to adapt this part

Comment: `CACHE_TIMEOUT` is defined in config.php. I have used this everywhere else in the application.

Comment: try the command that I posted with 3600 instead of self::CACHE_TIMEOUT and telle me if it works

Comment: Then I don't know what's wrong, may be try to define the dependency in the foreach loop, to have a different dependency on each request but I really don't think it's the problem

Comment: above for loop i have another query which works, using same depndancy. the result gets cached. i have updated question

Comment: and if you put $dependancy = new CDbCacheDependency("select last_modified_date from projects where PROJID = $projid"); again in your foreach loop does it work?

Comment: Glad you made it work, but the yii guide indicate that you can cache with DAO: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching